# Weird compile errors implementing OnImageCapturedCallback() for taking picture with androidx

Tags: java, android-camerax

All the examples of invoking the Android camera with androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture are in Kotlin or are really out of date, and I am getting weird compilation errors with Java.

```
androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture imageCapture;
...
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
     imageCapture = new ImageCapture.Builder()
                        .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY)
                        .build();
...
}

public void snapQRCode(View view) {
        imageCapture.takePicture(executor, new androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback(){
            void onCaptureSuccess(ImageProxy image){}
            void onError(ImageCaptureException exception) {}
        }
        );
}
```

This throws a compile error:

> error: onCaptureSuccess(ImageProxy) in anonymous 
>   xyz.MainActivity$1 cannot override
>   onCaptureSuccess(ImageProxy) in OnImageCapturedCallback
>               void onCaptureSuccess(ImageProxy image){}

I am confused because ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback is abstract.  I shouldn't be overriding at all.  I am pretty sure I have the camera configured correctly, but if someone could explain this error, and perhaps provide a few lines of (Java) code that snaps the picture and returns the image, that would be much appreciated.

Here are the libraries I am using in app/build.gradle:

```
def cameraxVersion = "1.0.0-beta03"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:${cameraxVersion}"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:${cameraxVersion}"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:${cameraxVersion}"
```

Comment: I guess you are missing some modifiers, try `public void onCaptureSuccess(ImageProxy image){}` etc.

Comment: I am embarrassed to say that that worked!  I was positive I had tried that in going around and around.  But there it is.  I did get it to work first thing this morning by going into the source code for ImageCapture.java, and seeing what they did there.  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. In fact I was quite sure, I tend to forget the modifiers now and then, too ;-)